# How to use a foreign key to relate to a different table's ID

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys

I'm trying to make a shopping list app and I have a shopping list entity and a shopping list item entity. The shopping list should have an ID key and some extra variables that don't matter. The shopping list item should have an ID key and a Foreign Key that relates to its shopping list's ID. How would I go about doing this? I'm getting a UpdateDatabaseException. Or if there is a better way to do this I would appreciate learning how

ShoppingList

```
public class ShoppingList
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

ShoppingListItem

```
public class ShoppingListItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ShoppingList")]
    public int ShoppingListId { get; set; }
{
```

If you need anymore classes just ask. I don't want to bloat this thread

New exception I'm getting

```
"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.ShoppingListItem_dbo.ShoppingList_ShoppingListId\". The conflict occurred in database \"ShoppingListApp\", table \"dbo.ShoppingList\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."
```

Comment: Now I'm getting another weird error. Ill update thread with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if anything is incorrect in my understanding. A shopping list Table will have an id (its primary key) and other columns and a column/columns representing shopping list item information.

**One to Many Relationship** 
  representation :

ShoppingList --> ShoppingListItem1 , ShoppingListItem2, ShoppingListItem3 etc.

where ShoppingListItem1 , ShoppingListItem2 etc point to entries in ShoppintListItem Table.

Hence , from that the classes structure should look like this :

```
public class ShoppingList
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ShoppingListItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ShoppingListItemId")]
    public ShoppingListItem ShoppingListItem { get; set; }
}

public class ShoppingListItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

Reference for adding annonations over Properties to mark them as Primary and Foreign keys :

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Also if you want to have Foreign Key in ShoppingListItem table and it points to Shopping List Table , then the code and possible correction for the issue you are facing should be this :

```
public class ShoppingList
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Other Properties
}

public class ShoppingListItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //other properties

    public int ShoppingListId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ShoppingListId")]
    public ShoppingList ShoppingList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was working so I couldn't reply back. This still has the problem that the FK doesn't automatically get generated when created based on ShoppingList's ID

Answer (score 0):

I was totally wrong. Your POCO is fine. The error is that you are trying to insert foreign key value that doesn't exist in the primary key table.

Comment: If I have a shoppinglist with an id of 1 and make a new item on that shoppinglist, the FK of the item will be 1 also?

Comment: Yea now I'm getting the DatabaseUpdateException. Updating thread with this one.

Comment: You are trying to insert foreign key value that doesn't exist in the primary key table

Comment: This is incorrect. The `ForeignKey` attribute can be applied either way, you just need to reference either the key property or the navigation property, respectively. In other words, the way the OP had it is just fine, since it's applied to `ShoppingListId` but references `ShoppingList`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt... You are right. I never used the other way